# An inequality relating to maximal functions and convolutions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, let us denote the restricted maximal function $Mf$ as
$$(Mf)(x)=\sup_{0<t<1}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}|f(z)|\,dz.$$
I would like to show that
$$M(f*g)\le M(f)*M(g)$$
for all $f, g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

I computed
$$M(f*g)(x) =\sup_{0<t<1}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(z-y)g(y)\,dy \right|\,dz\le \sup_{0<t<1}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(z-y)||g(y)|\,dy\,dz.$$
A change of variables shows that
$$M(f*g)(x) \le \sup_{0<t<1} \frac{1}{2t}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{-t}^{t} |f(z+x-y)||g(y)|\,dz\,dy= \frac{1}{2}\sup_{0<t<1} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{-1}^{1} |f(tz+x-y)||g(y)|\,dz\,dy$$
On the other hand, we have that
\begin{aligned}
(Mf)*(Mg)(x) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}Mf(x-y)Mg(y)\,dy \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\sup_{0<t<1}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-y-t}^{x-y+t}|f(z)|\,dz\right)\left(\sup_{0<t'<1}\frac{1}{2t'}\int_{y-t'}^{y+t'}|g(z')|\,dz'\right)\,dy \\ 
&= \sup_{0<t, t'<1} \frac{1}{4tt'} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-t}^{t}\int_{y-t'}^{y+t'} |f(z+x-y)| |g(z')|\,dz'\,dz\,dy.
\end{aligned}
It is starting to look promising but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Why is $$\sup_{t\in(0,1)}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}|f(z)|dz$$ not simply $$\int_{x-1}^{x+1}|f(z)|dz$$ ?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: $M(f*g)\leq (Mf)*|g|\leq Mf*Mg$. THe first inequality follows from what you already did. The last one follows from $|g|\leq Mg$ a.s. which follows from Lebesgue differentiation.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If you write that as an answer I will accept it.